# eslint Cannot find module 'node:fs' Require stack:

Tags: typescript, eslint, react-typescript, typescript-eslint, teams-toolkit

I am working on a teams app.
I have my tab in react and typescript. (if you are not aware of teams app, the tab can be considered as a individual react app)

I am initiating linting with help of es lint and prettier.

I am able to run my script and get the issues.
In fact I have resolved all of them.

When I start debugging my teams application,
I get this error:

`ERROR in [eslint] Cannot find module 'node:fs'
Require stack:

- /Users/teams_app/tabs/node_modules/synckit/lib/index.cjs
- /Users/teams_app/tabs/node_modules/eslint-plugin-prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier.js
- /Users/teams_app/tabs/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/dist/eslintrc.cjs
  Occurred while linting /Users/teams_app/tabs/src/components/tabs/wish-tab/Wish.tsx:1
  Rule: "prettier/prettier"`

Here's my eslintrc.json

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest",
    "airbnb",
    "airbnb-typescript",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module",
    "project": "./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "@typescript-eslint", "prettier"],
  "rules": {
    //my rules here
  }
}
```

Here's the list of dev dependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.4.2",
    "@types/react": "^16.14.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.12",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2"
  },
```

This is my folder structure [folder structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvAa7.png)
But on everyfile I get this error - seems like it is not taking the path correctly [path error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhVAU.png)

I tried downgrading "eslint-import-resolver-typescript" to "^2.7.1", and installing the latest node version. I am using 18.16.1
I upgraded the "@types/node" to "^20.4.2",

I am expecting it to run with out any error

Comment: `"@types/node": "^12.0.0",` doesn't match the version of Node you are using. It's *ancient*.

Comment: Updated "@types/node": "^20.4.2" but I get the same error. I have added few more details on the path error which might be a possible hint

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting this same issue and it seems like it's caused by this line in my eslintrc: `"plugin:prettier/recommended",`. Mine is a fresh install of ViteJS with airbnb's eslint and prettier. I'm not sure why the plugin wasn't working, but it mentions it's best when it's the only plugin. Luckily I didn't need it, read below.

This line is for the `plugin` that applies Prettier rules in eslint, so you'll see the red squiggly lines when something isn't right. I don't want eslint to remind me that I need to format it myself. https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier

I want to use the `config` prettier, that is a pre-defined set of rules for prettier. these are the rules that my `format` command will use. https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier

I changed this to just `"prettier"` in the extends object in my eslintrc which turns off some ESLint rules that conflict with Prettier. I also removed prettier from the plugins array in my eslintrc

`extends: ['prettier']`

`plugins: ['react-refresh', '@typescript-eslint']`